# Python web app 504 gateway timeout on Nginx and Gunicorn

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I'm running a Python web application upon Gunicorn and Nginx, on a Ubuntu server at Digital Ocean Droplet. The application times-out if the load is over 60s and goes to 504 Gateway Timeout page. I've made several changes to my nginx.conf file, by increasing the proxy timeout duration and I've tried I've increasing the gunicorn timeout duration.

Nothing seems to be working to resolve this issue, it's always return 504 after 60s.
Following are Nginx and gunicorn config sample. Appreciated for any help. Thanks!

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 900s;
proxy_connect_timeout 900s;
proxy_read_timeout 900s;
proxy_send_timeout 900s;
send_timeout 900s;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;
...
...
}
```

**I made sure to include --timeout 900 in Gunicorn config as well.**